# What's the origin of "to string somebody along"?

Tags: etymology

"to string somebody along", i.e. to deceive.

What's the origin of this phrase?

I always picture a cow being lead by the speaker with a piece of string.

Comment: You can find the etymology online.

Comment: I didn't close anything.

Answer (score 1):

According to Green’s Dictionary of Slang the original idea is probably that of being dragged along on a string:

***[string (along) v.](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/qcaqsvi)***:

> 1. in senses of persuasion [the image of dragging someone along on the end of a string].
>
> - (a) to fool, to deceive someone, esp. over a drawn-out period of time; to tease; thus stringing n.

Early usage examples:

> - 1812    [UK]    Vaux Vocab. of the Flash Lang. in McLachlan (1964) 251: *To banter or jest with a man by amusing him with false assurances or professions, is also termed stringing him, or getting him in tow.*
> - 1830    [UK]    W.T. Moncrieff Heart of London II i: *A very soft move his coming here, considering how he’s been strung by our Nottingham merchant here.*